# License for Plastic SCM 3.0 Community Ed

Tags: plasticscm

my license to the Community Ed just expired. Wondering how I can update the license without upgrading to 4 or 5, which I have been told will result in losing old branches with dynamic inheritance. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing and not about programming.

Answer (score -1):

The Plastic SCM support have contacted you in order to help with your license issue and renew your CE license.